# Hibernate: How to fix “identifier of an instance altered from 29 to 28

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm building a Java JSF application where we have a form to submit the details and upon entering the user details and clicking in submit the details will be saved in the database.

I'm able to save the data in the database table.
But I'm getting the
Here is the below warning.

Here is the warning I received in my console.

```
javax.el.ELException: /jsf/Details.xhtml 
@10,76 listener="#{javaMB.saveForm}": 
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.HibernateException:
 identifier of an instance of package.entity.VisaDetails was altered from 29 to 28; 
 nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException:
 identifier of an instance of package.entity.VisaDetails was altered from 29 to 28
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:111)
    at org.primefaces.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processArgListener(AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.java:84)
    at org.primefaces.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processAjaxBehavior(AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.java:74)
    at javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent.processListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent.java:113)
    at javax.faces.component.behavior.BehaviorBase.broadcast(BehaviorBase.java:106)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: 
identifier of an instance of package.entity.VisaDetails was altered from 29 to 28; 
nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException:
 identifier of an instance of package.entity.VisaDetails was altered from 29 to 28
```

Details.xhtml

```
                <p:commandButton id="saveDetailsId" value="Save"  ajax="true" type="button">
                                 <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form"/>
                    <p:ajax listener="#{javaMB.saveForm}"  />
                </p:commandButton>
```

JavaMB.saveform

```
    public void saveForm(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){
        
        this.visaDetailsEntity = this.getService().save(this.visaDetailsentity);       
       
    }
```

ServiceImpl class

```
@Override
@Transactional
public VisaDetails save(VisaDetails visaDetails) {          
    try 
        visaDetails = visaDetailsRepository.save(visaDetails);
        logger.debug(" [id:{}]" + visaDetails.getVisaDetailsId());
        return visaDetails;
    } 
    catch (RuntimeException re) 
    {
        TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
        logger.error("persist failed", re);
        throw re;
    }   
}
```

Entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "VISA_DETAILS", schema = "PROD_OWNR")

public class VisaDetails implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "VISA_DETAILS_ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "VISA_DETAILS_ID_SEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "VISA_DETAILS_ID_SEQ", sequenceName = "PROD_OWNR.VISA_DETAILS_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
private Long VisaDetailsId;
@Size(max = 32)
@Column(name = "CARD_NAME")
private String cardName;
public VisaDetails() {
}
public Long getVisaDetailsId() {
    return VisaDetailsId;
}
public void setVisaDetailsId(Long VisaDetailsId) {
    this.VisaDetailsId = VisaDetailsId;
}
public String getCardName() {
    return cardName;
}
public void setCardName(String cardName) {
    this.cardName = cardName;
}
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (VisaDetailsId != null ? VisaDetailsId.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    if (!(object instanceof VisaDetails)) {
        return false;
    }
    VisaDetails other = (VisaDetails) object;
    if ((this.VisaDetailsId == null && other.VisaDetailsId != null) || (this.VisaDetailsId != null && !this.VisaDetailsId.equals(other.VisaDetailsId))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "package.entity.VisaDetails[ VisaDetailsId=" + VisaDetailsId + " ]";
}
}
```